# boost::program_options (command line parser) alternative that can process arguments in order

Tags: library, software-development, c++, command-line

I've posted the following question on SO, but I guess `boost::program_options` can't help me here:

> I have options `--foo` (short form `-f`) and `--bar` that need special treatment, they are repeatable and order should matter. So, for the following:
>
> ```
> program --foo 1 --z -f 2 --bar 3 --x --foo 4
> ```
>
> I'd like to range a key value map being able to construct `[("foo", 1), ("foo", 2), ("bar", 3), ("foo", 4)]`.
>
> Please notice the order of this array of tuples, it's the same as that in the command line. I've discarded non-important options in the array, but they may be present in the command line nonetheless.
>
> It seems the sole way to allow repeatable options with `boost::program_options` is calling `composing()` for any given option, but then, since each will store all their values in a vector, I lose the order I need for interlacing options.
>
> So, can `boost::program_options` help with this?

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973114/

I'm looking for a library that allows me to range through the parsed options (if possible with their names normalized to their long or short names) in the order it's given in the command line because such order is important for me.

Comment: I know that `program_options` can give you everything it didn't parse itself as a `vector<string>`. In fact, I use [this ugly piece of code](https://gist.github.com/eyalroz/011060ea931e1704d0dbc60cedc6d5b0) to put it into a key-value map in a project I'm working on, and it shouldn't be difficult to adapt to what you need I guess.

Comment: Ah, there it is: `boost::program_options::collect_unrecognized()`. Although I will say you probably shouldn't be assuming order for command-line options, i.e. the problem is more in the fact that you're trying to do this IMO.

Comment: @einpoklum no, there's no issue I think in trying to do this, the reason is that I need to do something like `matrix_product_program --matrix="{...}" --matrix="{...}" --matrix="{...}"`. Any problem with having to fit this situation with a solution as explained?

Comment: You do know the command-line is not the place to put input data, right? Can't you get the number of matrices from the command line, then just read them (say line-by-line) from standard input? Anyway, you got a +1 from me since something more versatile than `boost::program_options` is interesting.

Comment: @einpoklum also, thanks for these pointers, probably it's going to be of great help, I'll check them out.

Comment: @einpoklum that was just to illustrate, since matrix product doesn't commute. Standard input is not an option for me, since in truth, my case is not about matrices and complex input data, but just simple strings.

Comment: @einpoklum well, given the context of this `collect_unrecognized` and the snippet you sent.... It doesn't look nice as I expected. See that I even mention about getting normalized (implying it was recognized) option names, coupled with corresponding values.

Comment: Well, I did warn you it was ugly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Poco, which calls a callback per flag, in order:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <Poco/Util/Option.h>
#include <Poco/Util/OptionSet.h>
#include <Poco/Util/Application.h>
#include <Poco/Util/HelpFormatter.h>

using Poco::Util::Option;
using Poco::Util::OptionSet;
using Poco::Util::Application;
using Poco::Util::HelpFormatter;
using Poco::Util::OptionCallback;

struct SampleApp : Application {
    void defineOptions(OptionSet &options) {
        Application::defineOptions(options);

        options.addOption(Option("help", "h", "display help information")
                              .required(false)
                              .repeatable(false)
                              .callback(OptionCallback<SampleApp>(
                                  this, &SampleApp::handleHelp)));

        options.addOption(Option("foo", "f", "foo option")
                              .required(false)
                              .repeatable(true)
                              .argument("<foo>")
                              .callback(OptionCallback<SampleApp>(
                                  this, &SampleApp::handleOptions)));

        options.addOption(Option("bar", "b", "bar option")
                              .required(false)
                              .repeatable(false)
                              .argument("<bar>")
                              .callback(OptionCallback<SampleApp>(
                                  this, &SampleApp::handleOptions)));

        options.addOption(Option("z", "", "z option")
                              .required(false)
                              .callback(OptionCallback<SampleApp>(
                                  this, &SampleApp::handleOptions)));

        options.addOption(Option("x", "", "x option")
                              .required(false)
                              .callback(OptionCallback<SampleApp>(
                                  this, &SampleApp::handleOptions)));
    }

    void handleHelp(const std::string &, const std::string &) {
        helpRequested = true;
        displayHelp();
        stopOptionsProcessing();
    }

    void handleOptions(const std::string &name, const std::string &value) {
        std::cout << name << " " << value << std::endl;
    }

    void displayHelp() {
        HelpFormatter helpFormatter(options());
        helpFormatter.setCommand(commandName());
        helpFormatter.setUsage("<options>");
        helpFormatter.setHeader("Foo/Bar options.");
        helpFormatter.format(std::cout);
    }

    bool helpRequested = false;
};

POCO_APP_MAIN(SampleApp)
```

---

### OUTPUT

```
❯❯❯ ./sample --help
usage: sample <options>
Foo/Bar options.

-h, --help            display help information
-f<foo>, --foo=<foo>  foo option
-b<bar>, --bar=<bar>  bar option
--z                   z option
--x                   x option
❯❯❯ ./sample --foo 1 --z -f 2 --bar 3 --x --foo 4
foo 1
z 
foo 2
bar 3
x 
foo 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest master in [CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11) (will be in version 1.1) (now an official example as well):

```
#include <CLI/CLI.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    CLI::App app;

    std::vector<int> foos;
    auto foo = app.add_option("--foo,-f", foos);

    std::vector<int> bars;
    auto bar = app.add_option("--bar", bars);

    app.add_flag("--z,--x"); // Random other flags

    try {
        app.parse(argc, argv);
    } catch(const CLI::ParseError &e) {
        return app.exit(e);
    }

    // I perfer using the back and popping
    std::reverse(std::begin(foos), std::end(foos));
    std::reverse(std::begin(bars), std::end(bars));

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> keyval;
    for(auto option : app.parse_order()) {
        if(option == foo) {
            keyval.emplace_back("foo", foos.back());
            foos.pop_back();
        }
        if(option == bar) {
            keyval.emplace_back("bar", bars.back());
            bars.pop_back();
        }
    }

    // Prove the vector is correct
    for(auto &pair : keyval) {
        std::cout << pair.first << " : " << pair.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
./examples/inter_argument_order --foo 1 --z -f 2 --bar 3 --x --foo 4
foo : 1
foo : 2
bar : 3
foo : 4
```